# webpack and yarn struggling to load modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, yarnpkg

I've run into this issue for a while now, and there seems to be a pattern so I'm assuming that the problem lies in the way I have webpack setup.

I'm using Ruby on Rails 6 which uses webpack (or webpacker, the rails wrapper) to install npm packages. However, webpacker uses yarn. Two packages that I've added yield very similar errors that make my entire site not work anymore.

**Error 1:**

when I yarn add: `bootstrap-fileinput` and run the import statement in my scss file and the import statement in my js file, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../img/loading.gif'
```

**Error 2:**
When I yarn add `gritter` and run the import statement in my scss file and the import statement in my js file, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../images/ie-spacer.gif'
```

Perhaps yarn isn't installing these gifs? or maybe webpack can't find them? This isn't happening with all the npm packages I add, but some of them do throw this error and if I find anymore I'll add them here.

This might have to do with how I have webpack setup, i.e., with regards to having certain loaders, but I could be wrong.

Any help is appreciated.